# Find links with image format at the end of address link (such as jpg, png, gif, etc.)

Tags: jquery

I need this code to take a **different size letters** - image format such as "**jpg** and **JPG**, **gif** and **GIF**" etc.
Also not to take it, for example, not where "**.jpg**" **at the end of the link**, to it for nothing as "**jpg.html**".
It is also possible to add that the **exemption did not want to look for domain** "**imageshack**"?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.postlink').filter(function() {
            return $(this).attr('href').match(/\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)/);
        }).addClass('lightview');
    });
```

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.postlink').filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr('href').match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)/i);
    }).addClass('lightview');
});
```